How to Configure AWS SES with Flask-Security-Too for Email Sending? (ValueError: No email extension configured)
I am attempting to switch from SMTP to AWS SES for sending emails in my Flask application, which uses Flask-Security-Too for user authentication and email management.
I have implemented the following configuration changes to integrate AWS SES:
app.config['SECURITY_MAIL_UTIL'] = SESMailUtil(app)
app.config['SECURITY_EMAIL_SENDER'] = read_config("EMAIL", 'notifications').get("sender_name")
app.config['SECURITY_EMAIL_SUBJECT_REGISTER'] = 'Welcome! Confirm your email'

SESMailUtil class:
from app_utils import get_ses_client
from flask_security.mail_util import MailUtil

class SESMailUtil(MailUtil):
    def __init__(self, app=None):
        super().__init__(app)
    def send_mail(self, template, subject, recipient, sender, body, html, user, **kwargs):
        ses_client = get_ses_client()
        try:
            response = ses_client.send_email(
                Source=sender,
                Destination={
                    'ToAddresses': [recipient]
                },
                Message={
                    'Subject': {'Data': subject},
                    'Body': {
                        'Text': {'Data': body},
                        'Html': {'Data': html}
                    }
                }
            )
            print(f"Email sent! Message ID: {response['MessageId']}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error sending email: {e}")

However, when I run the code, I encounter the following error:
raise ValueError("No email extension configured")
ValueError: No email extension configured

The correct config variable is SECURITY_MAIL_UTIL_CLS - pass in the class name and it will be instantiated as part of flask-security init_app(). You can also pass the class name in as part of the constructor.
